# WebSockets on Chrome 21

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I'm new to WebSockets. I read a lot of info on the subject and i'm trying to build a simple server just to handle the handshake part, but still can't get my server to work properly. The client sends the request, the server sends a response back to the client, but it won't fire the onopen event for the WebSocket. But if I close the server, the websocket object fires it's onclose event.

The request I get from chrome is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 192.168.0.164:3215
Origin: http://lalala
Sec-WebSocket-Key: MyUY7duPdE1WbGXPOslYzw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

The response I send back:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 4IVZgO4OosW/b7upp7Qbh2q6a4I=
```

The code i'm using in the server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.164"), 3215);
      listener.Start();
      Console.WriteLine(">> Started.");
      var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
      Console.WriteLine(">> Accepted.");
      while (true)
      {
        try
        {
          var stream = client.GetStream();
          var bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
          stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
          var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

          Console.WriteLine(data.Remove(data.IndexOf("\0\0\0")));
          var code = data.Remove(0, data.IndexOf("Sec-WebSocket-Key:") + 19);
          code = code.Remove(code.IndexOf("==") + 2);
          var response = string.Format(@"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + GetServerResponseKey(code));
          Console.WriteLine(response);
          var encodedResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
          stream.Write(encodedResponse, 0, encodedResponse.Length);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(">> Client Disconnected.");
          Console.ReadKey();
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    private static string GetServerResponseKey(string key)
    {
      var keyForHash = String.Concat(key, "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");

      var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
      var temp = encoding.GetBytes(keyForHash);

      var hashProvider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
      var keyForBase64 = hashProvider.ComputeHash(temp);

      return Convert.ToBase64String(keyForBase64);

    }
```

And the client script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var socket;
        function connect()
        {
          socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.164:3215');
          setTimeout(bindEvents, 1000);
          setReadyState();
        }

        function bindEvents() {
            socket.onopen = function() {
                alert('handshake successfully established. May send data now...');
                setReadyState();
            };
            socket.onclose = function() {
                alert('connection closed');
            };
        }

        function setReadyState() {
          console.log('ws.readyState: ' + socket.readyState);
        }
        connect();

    </script>
```

Some more questions:

1-Is there a way that I can find out which protocol my browser uses?

2-Which protocol Chrome 21 uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response needs to follow the rules for HTTP request/responses and have a carriage return + line feed between each header and a pair at the end. Instead of using new lines in the response I would escape encode them:

"header1\r\nheader2\r\nheader3\r\n\r\n"

The "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" header indicates that the browser is using version 13 of the protocol which is [IETF 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).